# String passed with spaces inside javascript onclick function does not get recognised

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Below is the code snippet

```
var docd = {message: 'hi'};

chatHTML += `<div class="message"> ${docd.message} </div>
     <i class="fas fa-reply" onclick=expand('${docd.message}')></i>
         </div>`;

$(".message-container").html(chatHTML);

function expand(message,)
{
console.log(message);
}
```

So the above code works just Fine.

Now if i change the variable value as

`var docd = {message: 'hi hello how are you'};  // Added spaces inbetween`

Now when the `onclick` event is called I am getting a error as

> Unexpected or Invalid token

Is it because the second string what i am passing is having spaces? Or is there any other issues? How to solve this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try using `(backtick) instead of ''

Comment: `onclick=expand('${docd.message})` must be `onclick=expand('${docd.message}')` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have missing quotation marks in your HTML `onclick` attribute. Instead of building HTML as a string, consider using the jQuery methods that link the handler via JavaScript:

```js
var docd = {message: 'hi there'};

$(".message-container").append(
    $("<div>").addClass("message").text(docd.message).append(
         $("<i>").addClass("fas fa-reply").click(() => expand(docd.message))
    )
);

function expand(message,) {
    console.log(message);
}
```

```css
.fa-reply:before {
    content: "⮪"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message-container"></div>
```

Comment: That's the only answer that addresses the issues with string escaping in the OP's question. There's your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the quotes around the value of the attribute `onclick`: `onclick="expand('${docd.message}')"` and also there is no text inside the `i` element, so I just added "test". I see no problem with spaces missing.

```js
var docd = {
  message: 'hi there'
};

var chatHTML = `<div class="message"> ${docd.message} </div>
     <i class="fas fa-reply" onclick="expand('${docd.message}')">test</i>
         </div>`;

$(".message-container").html(chatHTML);

function expand(message, ) {
  console.log(message);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick is missing double-quotes as well as single-quotes around the function and the function parameter.

In your `<i>` tag, change this:

```
onclick=expand('${docd.message}')
```

To this:

```
onclick="expand('${docd.message}')"
```

Check and run the Code Snippet below for a live example of the above corrected code (Vanilla JS version):

```js
function expand(message){
    console.log(message);
}

let chatHTML ='';
var docd = {message: 'hi hello how are you'};



chatHTML += `<div class="message"> ${docd.message} </div>
     <i class="fas fa-reply" onclick="expand('${docd.message}')">Click Me</i>
         </div>`;

document.querySelector('.someElement').innerHTML += chatHTML;
```

```html
<section class="someElement"></section>
```

But as @julien.giband pointed out, this approach will have issues with escaping quotes if `docd.message` has a quote in it. You can prevent the escaping issue by using an event listener instead like this:

```js
let chatHTML ='';
var docd = {message: `hi hello's how are"s you`};



chatHTML += `<div class="message"> ${docd.message} </div>
     <i class="fas fa-reply">Click Me</i>`;
         
document.querySelector('.chatHTML').innerHTML += chatHTML;

document.querySelector('i.fa-reply').addEventListener('click', () => console.log(`${docd.message}`));
```

```html
<section class="chatHTML"></section>
```

Comment: There are much bigger problems with escapes and using variable values instead of variables themselves here. What will happen to ` `expand('${docd.message}')` ` when the message contains a single quote `'`? What result will this yield? Same questions to @chrwahl

Comment: @julien.giband Good point. Answer updated.